# Android AsyncTask and SQLite DB instance

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, sqliteopenhelper

I have a problem and I am not sure how to approach it. An activity in my app has multiple `AsyncTask`s which access single `SQLiteOpenHelper`. I initialize and open the helper in `onCreate()` and I am closing it in `onStop()`. I also check if it has been initialized in `onResume()`.

Since I have published my app I received number of errors with Null Exception in `doInBackground` where I try to access the DB helper. I know that this is happens because the DB is closed ( `onStop()` ) just before the `doInBackground` is called, fair enough.

My question is, where should I close the DB connection? Is it right to use a single instance of the DB helper in the Activity and access it from multiple threads(`AsyncTasks`)? Or I should use separate DB helper instance for each `AsyncTask`?

This is a simplified skeleton of my activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    private DbHelper mDbHelper;
    private ArrayList<ExampleObject> objects;

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(mDbHelper != null){
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDbHelper = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(mDbHelper == null){
            mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
            mDbHelper.open();
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle); 
        DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
    }

    private class DoSomething extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            objects = mDbHelper.getMyExampleObjects();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused){
            //update UI with my objects
        }
    }

    private class DoSomethingElse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            objects = mDbHelper.getSortedObjects();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused){
            //update UI with my objects
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you cancel the AsyncTask before closing the DB. But you should keep in mind that cancelling the AsyncTask just signals the task to be cancelled and you need to check isCancelled() in doInBackground() and do the needful to stop DB operations.

Before closing the DB, you then need to check getStatus() to be sure that the AsyncTask has stopped.

Comment: So basically I should use while(!isCancelled){} in doInBackground and perform all calculation inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, and check getStatus() in your main thread to be sure that the AsyncTask has ended.

Comment: OK but what if I check it in onStop() and it hasn't ended? Where would I close DB connection then?

Comment: For an AsyncTask, it is recommended that you should exit doInBackground as early as possible when a cancel signal has been raised. So, within the while loop in doInBackground, whenever you are about to execute a DB statement, check for isCancelled() and break from there if it is true.
In the onStop() on the main thread, you should loop with sleep and wait for the AsyncTask to complete before closing the DB connection.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to manage db connection for each activity. You can do it in an instance of android.app.Application and access db using this instance. 
Something like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    // Synchronized because it's possible to get a race condition here
    // if db is accessed from different threads. This synchronization can be optimized
    // thought I wander if it's necessary
    public synchronized static SQLiteDatabase db() {
        if(self().mDbOpenHelper == null) {
            self().mDbOpenHelper = new MyDbOpenHelper();
        }
        return self().mDbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public static Context context() {
        return self();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mSelf = this;
    }

    private static MyApplication self() {
        if (self == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
        return mSelf;
    }

    private MyDbOpenHelper mDbOpenHelper;

    private static MyApplication mSelf;
}
```

This way you can be sure you Db is always accessible.

And yes, having one instance of Db helper is a good practice. Thread syncronisation is made for you by default.

Comment: One more question...where would you close DB connection?

Comment: I don't close it. Wonder if it's really necessary. If you can find more details on this please share, it's interesting. Thought I never hand any problems with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for getting beck to me. I will try to investigate this bit more

Comment: If you are still interested, I have seen the connection being closed in the `onTerminate` method of `Application`.

Comment: "This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so." from API documentation

Comment: if some want this example with full code just go here... http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/android-database-example-database-usage-asynctask-database-export/

Answer (score 5):

It is good to use a single `DB Helper`.
The problem is that when the user leaves the `Activity` the `DB` is closed but the `AsyncTask` may still run. So you should check that the `DB` is not null when you are trying to access it, and if it is `null` this may mean that your `Activity` was destroyed and `cancel` that task.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I forgot to mention that I have also got few Exceptions saying 'unable to close due to unfinalised statements'. That probably means that I try to close the DB connection in onStop() while the query is executing in doInBackground(). I cancel the AsyncTask before clsoing the DB but I still get this error. Any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: @Ovidiu Where do you usually put the DB initialization and cleanup code? (Suppousing there's a DBHelper being accesed by several views).

Comment: as @boulder said it may be a good practice to keep it in Application